# BitTorrent Speed support for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: bittorrent, torrent-client

Recently I learned of the BitTorrent Speed feature and the BTT cryptocurrency (https://www.bittorrent.com/token/bittorrent-speed/) and would like to use it on Ubuntu.

I know that the default Ubuntu flavor bundles Transmission by default, but it seems that the BitTorrent Speed feature is only supported by BitTorrent Classic (which I believe used to be called uTorrent) and BitTorrent Web. Both are only available for Windows. I already tried running the installers under WINE, and both crashed.

Is there a native BitTorrent client for Ubuntu 20.04 (or Linux in general) that supports the BitTorrent Speed feature?

Comment: Since this is a feature of the BitTorrent (organization) application, not of torrents generally, and since BitTorrent does not have a native Linux client, the answer you are looking for seems unlikely.

Comment: Yeah, right now I use virt-manager and run a Win 10 VM inside my Ubuntu host, but it can be slow at times.

Comment: Might just be easier to use a Linux torrent app and a crypto mining app.  Bittorrent might make it easier to run, but I bet they are skimming some from you.  They not in business just to make you money.

Comment: That is true, BitTorrent Speed does use some of the in-app balance to leech torrents faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work fine with Wine, so no need for VM or Windows :)

Comment: I just retried the installer under Wine 6.0.0, and it works! Thanks a lot!